# ffmpeg silencedetect -ss argument

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to detect silence in a part of a sound file

```
ffmpeg -i 3.mp3 -ss 00:22:00 -to 00:23:30 -af "silencedetect=noise=-18dB:d=0.15,ametadata=mode=print:file=vol.txt" -f null -
```

This code detects silence from the beginning of the file to the value of **-to**.

Is it possible to print only **lavfi.silence_end** and **lavfi.silence_start**? How to pass it to

```
"silencedetect=noise=-18dB:d=0.15,ametadata=mode=print:file=vol.txt"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the select filter instead:

```
ffmpeg -i 3.mp3 -af "aselect='between(t,1320,1410)',silencedetect=noise=-18dB:d=0.15,ametadata=mode=print:file=vol.txt" -f null -
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I goa an error `[Parsed_aselect_0 @ 000000000041ab80] [Eval @ 000000000022e730] Missing ')' or too many args in 'between(t,22:00,23:30)'
[Parsed_aselect_0 @ 000000000041ab80] Error while parsing expression 'between(t,22:00,23:30)'
[AVFilterGraph @ 000000000053d340] Error initializing filter 'aselect' with args 'between(t,22\:00,23\:30)'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
Conversion failed!`

Comment: Times have to be in seconds. Corrected.

Comment: @[Mulvya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5726027/mulvya) Outstanding! **Thanks a lot!**